# Accessing a DIV inside a Form?

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing, dom

I am trying to access the DIV with the id "codeDef" using

```
document.getElementById['codeDef']
```

But it returns "undefined".What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the HTML snippet :

```
<div class="section">
<div class="box">
<form method="post" name="exam-company-input-form" action="./">
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<td style="width:150px;padding-left:20px">
Exam Code
</td>
<td style="width:150px;padding-left:20px"><input type="text" maxlength="10" style="width:100%" value="" name="code" onkeyup="javascript:checkExamCode();"></td><td><div id="codeDef">code def</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td style="width:150px;padding-left:20px">
Orca Code
</td>
<td style="width:150px;padding-left:20px"><input type="text" maxlength="10" style="width:100%" value="" name="srycd" onkeyup="javascript:checkOrcaCode();"></td><td id="orcaDef">orca def</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="text-align:center" colspan="3">
<button style="opacity: 1; margin-right: 15px;" onclick="javascript:ResetForm('exam-company-input-form');" class="blue" type="button"><span>リセット</span>
</button><button style="opacity: 1;" onclick="javascript:SubmitForm('exam-company-input-form');" class="blue" type="button"><span>登&#12288;録</span>
</button></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
<input type="hidden" value="master_exam-company-input-do" name="pid">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answers.since there are many correct once,im going to select the one with the least reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementById("idName")`

Use parentheses

Comment: @ashika haha no problem, that happens sometimes -- sometimes very hard to spot simple errors

Answer (score 3):

It should be `document.getElementById('codeDef')`.

If you use `[]`, it means you want to get the property `codeDef` of the Function `document.getElementId`, and obviously, there is no such property, so you will get `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a function, try

```
document.getElementById('codeDef')
```

Instead of

```
document.getElementById['codeDef']
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
   document.getElementById('codeDef');
```